# Deck of Cards Problem, having issue with the C Functions

Tags: c

I'm just a beginner so your help is greatly appreciated. In the code below I'm receiving errors, it seems that I did something wrong with the function. The program output is listed below, it supposes to randomly generate a list as shown in the picture.

Any suggestions on how to fix this program, please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void random_shuffle(deck, deck+52)   {
    
}

/* initialize suit array */
const char *suit[ 4 ] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
/* initialize face array */
const char *face[ 13 ] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
                           "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
                           "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

void for_each(int *start, int *end, void(*f)(int)) {
    for (int *cur = start; cur < end; cur++) {
        f(*cur);
    }
    
    
    
}

void print_card(int n) {
    printf("%s of %s\n", face[n % 13], suit[n / 13]);
}

void shuffleAndDeal( int workdeck[][ 13 ], const char *workface[], const char *worksuit[] ) {
//  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int deck[52];

    // Prime, shuffle, dump
    for (int i=0;i<52;i++) {
        deck[i] = i;
    }
    random_shuffle(deck, deck+52);
    for_each(deck, deck+52, print_card);
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
/* initialize deck array */
    int deck[ 4 ][ 13 ] = { 0 };
    shuffleAndDeal( deck, face, suit );
    return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
}
```

[![output][1]][1]

**Below are the errors I'm getting**

````
 void random_shuffle(deck, deck+52)   {
                               ^
main.c: In function ‘shuffleAndDeal’:
main.c:36:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘random_shuffle’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     random_shuffle(deck, deck+52);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: At top level:
main.c:47:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#tab-stdin
      ^```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF7tl.png
````

Comment: What is `void random_shuffle(deck, deck+52)` supposed to mean?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write something other than C in C. If you want to use C effectively you should probably stick to writing more idiomatic C code. `for_each` is an example of trying to force a square peg into a round hole. In C we just write a `for` loop and get it over with.

Comment: *I'm receiving errors*. If you are getting errors wouldn't it be common sense to tell people what those errors are?

Comment: Tip: Standard computer card notation is two characters, like `AS` or `2D` or `TC` where it's digits or `AKQJT` with `T` for 10.

Comment: Tip: Pick *one* naming convention and stick with it. Seeing both underscore style like `print_card` and camelcase like `shuffleAndDeal` is really confusing.

Comment: I have added the expected output so you understand my code.

Comment: Adding the expected output does not in itself tell us what your errors are or what specific problem you have. And please add it as text and not as an image.

Comment: So, could you describe the errors more specificly? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `void random_shuffle(deck, deck+52)`. So if you compare that function declaration to all the other function declarations do you not notice anything different? That's clearly not a valid function declaration. Can't tell you what it is supposed to be as you have not stated clearly what the inputs are meant to be.

Comment: Added the errors I'm receiving and had to remove the output picture.

Comment: You should stop making up syntax.  You cannot yet program in C.  Go back and try simpler examples until you understand function declarations, definitions, arguments and parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This ...

> ```
> void random_shuffle(deck, deck+52)   {
>
> }
> ```

... is not a valid C function definition.  You must express a type and a distinct identifier for each function parameter.  You do not specify a type for either parameter, and `deck+52` is not (only) an identifier.

Comment: How should I declare and define the random_shuffle correctly in C?

Comment: @user3785208, as I already said, you must specify a type and a distinct identifier for each parameter. You already have other functions you could look to as examples.